# Does readying class features require concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, readied-action, concentration

I'm interested in getting an answer for class features in general, but the specific case that came up for me was the following:

A Grave domain cleric chose to ready Path to the Grave to use before another player's turn. They took some damage while they had the action readied, and so we ruled that they need to make a Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration.

Was this correct to do?

Does readying class features require concentration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## *No concentration required

The use of Path to the Grave uses the cleric's Channel Divinity ability and does not require the additional rules around concentration that spells do.

Taking a Ready action to use their Channel Divinity does not require concentration because it is not a spell. This is simply an action that is awaiting a trigger that is no way different than readying an attack or a movement. They haven't actually 'done' it yet, they are waiting on a trigger to do it. They can either get their trigger and use their action, or the trigger never comes, or they opt not to do it for some reason.

But there is no concentration involved, so moving forward I would recommend discussing what happened and what will happen in the future (no concentration checks).

Comment: For the general answer, I'd probably argue that it doesn't require concentration (barring house-ruling) because nothing in the rules says it does. For spells, you're casting the spell itself immediately and holding its energy (i.e. holding back its effect) until the trigger. There's no such equivalent requirement/process for non-spells; you just wait until the trigger occurs and then take the readied action. As such, any consumable resource required for the action (e.g. Channel Divinity) also wouldn't be consumed unless the trigger occurred and the readied action was taken using your reaction.

Comment: @V2Blast I've generally got the same conclusion, but for some reason it feels kinda weird if there is a concentration mechanic in place for the action and just don't feel 100% confident (yet.)

Comment: To be fair, the act of readying any spell requires concentration, even if the spell itself doesn't normally require concentration. :P

Comment: @V2Blast Thought about that! I had a counter argument in my head, but it's losing rapidly. I was thinking more about how I picture it working rather than the pure mechanics (which is fine), but for this answer it really is clear. Will work on an update.